# Get Previous and Current Value from HTTP call Angular2

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services, behaviorsubject

I have a scenario where i need to compare values obtained from initial service call and from new service call for same URL.

Service Class:

```
getXRate(): Observable {
   return this.http.get('someURL').subscribe((data) => { return data.json(); } );
}
```

Now, in `Component 1`, i call this service in `ngOnInit` like as below:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.service.getXRate().subscribe(data => this.r = data.r);
}
```

// **At this point i have first value**

> Now, in `component 2`, the same method is called to check if there is any difference between value returned in `Component 1`.

How can i achieve this?

*I tried using ReplaySubject and BehaviorSubject* but did not quite get out of it.

Comment: Can you tell why you want to compare , may be there is a better way to do that

Comment: I need comparision to alert user that there is change in x Rate. If yes he has to accept

Answer (score 0):

Have a service to store the last retrieved data for you and use it in your components.

Your existing code (please note that you subscribed to a subscription in the given example).
Some 'service':

```
lastObject: any;

storeLast(lastObject:any){
  this.lasObject = lastObject;
}

getLastObject(){
  return this.lastObject;
}

getXRate(){
  return this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json());
}
```

Component 1:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.service.getXRate().subscribe(res => this.service.storeLast(res));
}
```

Component 2:

```
getAndCompareLast(){
  let object = this.service.getLastObject();
  this.service.getXRate().subscribe(res => { //Do some compare logic...});
}
```

Comment: how about using some HTTP Caching? Can you let me know any examples for that?

Comment: Caching has nothing to do with comparing stored data, in this case specifically